# Traversing ByteStrings

Tags: string, haskell, traversal

I was reading [some random blog](http://honza.ca/2012/10/haskell-strings) where someone tries to perform a simple string processing operation in Haskell and gets rather slow code. Some of the problems with his (final, down the page a ways) code:

1. The whole file is read in at once.
2. He uses the relatively expensive `isSpace` and then compares the resulting program to C code that only considers simple spaces and newlines.
3. The way he uses `scanl` looks extremely pipeline-unfriendly, using a computed character as input to each step when that is not necessary.

The most natural approach, I think, is to use lazy `ByteString`s (as some of his earlier attempts do) and to scrap the `scanl` in favor of `zipWith'`, zipping the string with the string shifted over one: `zipWith f s (cons ' ' s)`

#### The problem

Zipping a lazy `ByteString` with a shifted version of itself doesn't take advantage of the relationship between the two strings. It performs many unnecessary checks for end-of-chunk and end-of-string. I'm sure I could write a specialized function that traverses a `ByteString` with a two-character "window", and I'm sure a better programmer than I could write one that takes advantage of the details of the chunk representation, but I'd prefer to find a more accessible approach. Any ideas?

Edited to add: another approach might be to use `foldr` to produce a `ByteString` builder, following the same general approach but using (hopefully unboxed) tuples to avoid data dependency; I'm not sure I quite understand those builders or their efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using the following imports.

```
import Data.Char 
import Data.List           
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T                      

import Criterion.Main
import Test.QuickCheck
```

I managed to get blazing speeds compared to this reference implementation from the blog post:

```
capitalize :: T.Text -> T.Text
capitalize = T.tail . T.scanl (\a b -> if isSpace a then toUpper b else b) ' '
```

Using `mapAccumL` is much faster. Here's `String` and `Text` versions.

```
{-# INLINE f #-}
f a b = (b, if isSpace a then toUpper b else b)

string :: String -> String
string = snd . mapAccumL f ' '

text :: T.Text -> T.Text
text = snd . T.mapAccumL f ' '
```

First, let's make sure that the optimization is valid

```
λ. quickCheck $ \xs -> 
    capitalize (T.pack xs) == text (T.pack xs)
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Now for some benchmark results from `criterion`, running each function on a 3.2 M file of Lorem Ipsum. Here's our reference speed.

```
benchmarking reference
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 56.19690 s
mean: 126.4616 ms, lb 126.0039 ms, ub 128.6617 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 4.432843 ms, lb 224.7290 us, ub 10.55986 ms, ci 0.950
```

`String` is only about 30% slower than the optimized reference `Text` version and the `mapAccumL` version using `Text` is almost twice as fast!

```
benchmarking string
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 16.45751 s
mean: 165.1451 ms, lb 165.0927 ms, ub 165.2112 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 301.0338 us, lb 250.2601 us, ub 370.2991 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking text
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 16.88929 s
mean: 67.67978 ms, lb 67.65432 ms, ub 67.72081 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 162.8791 us, lb 114.9346 us, ub 246.0348 us, ci 0.950
```

But there are even more easy gains to be had. `Data.Char.isSpace` is known for its performance issues, so lets try the fast `Data.Attoparsec.Char8.isSpace` instead. Our `quickcheck` test won't pass, but the performance is great.

```
benchmarking string/atto
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 12.91881 s
mean: 129.2176 ms, lb 129.1328 ms, ub 129.4941 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 705.3433 us, lb 238.2757 us, ub 1.568524 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking text/atto
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 15.76300 s
mean: 38.63183 ms, lb 38.62850 ms, ub 38.63730 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 21.41514 us, lb 15.27777 us, ub 33.98801 us, ci 0.950
```

We're now about `3x` faster than the original reference. For comparison, the very fast python code (which is just calling out to C),

```
print open('lorem.txt').read().title()
```

rips through the text file in `30ms`.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy I/O can be a problem, but it is the simplest way to approach this small task.

```
import Data.Text.Lazy (toTitle)
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO (readFile, putStr)
import Prelude hiding (readFile, putStr)

main = readFile "file" >>= putStr . toTitle
```

It will actually spend time doing Unicode (word-splitting and title-casing) correctly, but it's probably what you want.  If you want to avoid Lazy I/O, the pipes-text package should produce something that's not much bigger.

If you really want to treat everything as ASCII and assume all the words start with a letter, I still think lazy I/O is a win here, but it's a bit more complex.

```
import Data.Bits (.&.)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString, cons', putStrLn, readFile, uncons)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (lines, unlines, unwords, words)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Prelude hiding (putStrLn, readFile, lines, unlines, unwords, words)

capitalize :: ByteString -> ByteString
capitalize word = case uncons word of
  Just (h, t) -> cons' (h .|. complement 32) t
  Nothing     -> word

main = readFile "file"
   >>= putStrLn . unlines
                . map (unwords . map capitalize . words)
                . lines
```

Again, avoiding lazy I/O is as simple as using pipes-bytestring.

There was also a reddit thread about that post [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/120h6i/why_is_this_simple_text_processing_program_so/) and they seem to get great performance out of the Builder abstraction, plus a better way of upper-casing.  The builder abstraction probably will be faster than my bytestring hack because it will better chunk the output data before writing it.

Comment: Using `words` and `unwords` loses tabs and such, and mucking about with checking for empty words does indeed look like an ugly hack. Part of the problem is that the various "split-on" functions generally consume the separators, which isn't always the right thing. Semi-relatedly, nesting words/unwords within lines/unlines is ugly here, since there's no real distinction between the treatment of spaces and the treatment of newlines in the problem description.